# How to get a value from php url

Tags: php

I send data using header in php through this code.

```
$msg="ljqefnjnf";
header("Location: search.php?sms=".$msg);
```

and my url is :

```
localhost/search.php?sms=ljqefnjnf
```

How to get the sms data in search.php file

Comment: `echo $_GET['sms']` .

Answer (score 2):

use `$_GET`

```
$sms = $_GET['sms'];
```

Just see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) for more information

Comment: If i send a array then what should i do like this: $msg = array( "A", "B", "C" );

header("Location: search.php?sms=".$msg);

Comment: see this link, u can use `serialize()` for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098397/how-to-pass-an-array-in-get-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You need to use PHP's [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

```
$sms = $_GET['sms'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use PHP `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

```
$sms = $_GET['sms'];
$sms = $_REQUEST['sms'];
```

`$_REQUEST`, by default, contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

Answer (score 0):

The value you seek is in the `$_GET` array which holds all the values of arguments passed in through a URL.

In your case you would want to do this:

```
$message = $_GET['sms'];
```

But it could be anything in that array. For example if you have this URL `search.php?fruit=apple&color=purple` then you would do this:

```
$fruit = $_GET['fruit'];
$color = $_GET['color'];
```

You should note though, never blindly trust a user's input without validating it first. You can leave yourself open to attacks such as [Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601524/2233391)

Comment: If i send array then how I will do it like this : $msg = array( "A", "B", "C" );;

header("Location: search.php?sms=".$msg);

Comment: Whatever you add to the URL it needs to be valid for a url. You cannot send a raw PHP array in the $_GET array as far as I know. You would instead need to convert it to something else like a json array with `json_encode()` and then decode it at the other end with `json_decode`. You could also send it as a comma separated string or something if you have no keys. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, like @Rahautos said, you can use both $_GET or $_REQUEST global but don't forget that everything which is passed in your url can be "hijacked". You should make tests on what you get from it.

For example, never do that.

```
<?php
    $sms = $_GET['sms'];
    unlink($sms . '.php');
?>
```

You can do, instead of it

```
<?php
    $sms = $_GET['sms'];
    $allowed_files = array('conf', 'tmp');
    if (in_array($sms, $allowed_files) {
        unlink($sms . '.php');
    }
?>
```