# Pass multiple values of a HTTP request parameter

Tags: laravel, httprequest, laravel-5.6

How to pass multiple values of a single HTTP request parameter, and retrieve them in the controller?

Whether it be a repeated parameter like so:

```
http://example.com/users?q=1&q=2
```

or multiple values in a row like that:

```
http://example.com/users?q=1,2
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Laravel help page / user guide?

Comment: See by yourself, I saw nothing about multiple values parameters https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: Just grab them from the $_GET array (in the controller) provided that your route is http://example.com/users

Comment: I'm not sure about the first one, but the second approach gives you a string that you can split in your controller

Comment: $input = $request->all(); and then foreach?

Comment: @LeszekRepie You're conflating passing two different parameters and passing one parameter with several values.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi: use comma and then split into array? or array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098397/how-to-pass-an-array-in-get-in-php?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I wondered if it was implemented by Laravel, if I have to do `$list = explode(',',$req->q);` then the answer is no.

Comment: So you want to have one variable with multiple values?

Comment: No, in the controller I want to get an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an array to the request like this:

```
http://example.com/users?q[]=1&q[]=2
```

The `[]` will pass the parameter as an array. Therefore, when you retrieve the `q` from the request:

```
dd(request('q'));
```

It will give you the following:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
]
```

Comment: Are the `[]` characters 'normalized' for URL, like `?` and `&` for example or is this just a shorthand only available for Laravel (and not for Spring, etc.)? Can I do `?q[]=1,2`?

Comment: @JacopoStanchi Yes it is normalized for URL. You can do the way you suggested but it will pass a string into an array.

Answer (score 3):

Just like when you pass an html input with a value of array,
you can pass it with ***`[]`***. e.g. `/users?q[]=1&q[]=2`

```
Route::get('users', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    // when you dump the q parameter, you'll get:
    dd($request->q);
    // q = [1, 2]
});
```